# Getting Enthought Python Distribution to Cooperate with COPASI and libsbml

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been using the Enthought Python Distribution (the Academic version) for some time now, but have been trying to install some extra packages for a project, and running into problems born of my relative inexperience with the command line.

These are:

- COPASI
- libSBML
- StochPy

The last one went well, a simple `python setup.py install` and everything seems to be running fine. But neither COPASI nor libSBML seem to be working.

Importing either one of them is netting "ImportError: No module named COPASI/libsbml".

I installed libSBML according to the [directions here](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/python-api/libsbml-installation.html#unix-gnumake).And used [this suggested workaround](http://sbml.org/Forums/index.php?t=tree&th=1925&mid=7256&rid=0&rev=&reveal=) to get it working with Enthought, to no avail. For COPASI, I installed COPASI as directed, and followed the following directions for the Python bindings:

> Once you downloaded the binary package for the Java bindings you have to unpack it. It will be unpacked to a directory called copasi_python. This directory contains the native library, a python file, a documentation file and the license file. It also contains a directory called unittests with lots of unittests that can be used to check if the bindings are working.
>
> To run the unittests, you first have to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the directory where the native library and the COPASI.py file are located. Once you changed into the unittests directory you find a file called runTests.py which runs all the unittests in the directory.

My edited .bash_profile file now looks like this:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/COPASI/copasi35_python27_macosx107_x64:$PYTHONPATH
```

The first line is to make EPD the default python interpreter, the second is the result of the suggested workaround above, and the third is per the instructions for COPASI. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?